# Job 5.7 in the King James version

Tags: word-choice, christianity, ecclesiastical-latin, reference-request

This extract from the novel 'Three Men in a Boat' refers to Job 5.7:

> *This world is only a probation, and man was born to trouble as the sparks fly upward.*

I hoped to quote the source, expecting to find it in the Vulgate, — but it's not so simple.

1. Vulgate (AD 382): *homo ad laborem nascitur et avis ad volatum*
2. KJV (1611): *Man is born to trouble as the sparks fly upward.*
3. Luther (1545): *Sondern der Mensch wird zu unglück geborn / wie die Vögel schweben empor zufliegen.*
4. Gute nachricht Bibel (2017): *Aus seinem eigenen Wesen kommt das Leid, so wie der Funkenwirbel aus dem Feuer.*
5. bibleenligne.com (2017): *car l'homme est né pour la misère, comme les étincelles s'élèvent pour voler.* [lit. *les fils de la flamme*]

It isn't difficult to put into Latin (*homo nascitur ad laborem sicut scintilla ad volatum*), but **can anyone direct me to a Latin original for the King James version**, with sparks instead of the bird of  Jerome *et al* or explain why the difference came about?

Comment: What do you mean by Latin original for the KJV? Though it sometimes fell back on the Vulgate, the KJV was primarily translated from the original Hebrew.

Comment: This springs from a different interpretation of the Hebrew: the relevant word (וּבְנֵי־רֶ֝֗שֶׁף) apparently has a few interpretations, on whose merits I can't comment: one interpretation is "sons of burning coals" (=sparks) and another is "sons of vultures"--which is rendered as such in the LXX (νεοσσοὶ δὲ γυπὸς) and Vulgate (simply avis). I would make this an answer, but my Hebrew is too rudimentary for me to pretend I know what I'm talking about.

Comment: Ditto @C.M.Weimer, though: the KJV used the Hebrew original (probably compared to the LXX and Vulgate). If you want a (sometimes painfully) literal translation from the Vulgate, check out the [Douay Rheims](http://www.drbo.org/chapter/20005.htm).

Comment: [This Language Hat thread](http://languagehat.com/bene-reshep/) has some discussion of the "sparks" phrase, its Hebrew original, and various possible interpretations.

Comment: @brianpck, or Tom might be somehow satisfied by knowing that no one can direct him to a Latin original for the KJB? Tom?

Comment: @Rafael  When I asked this, I merely wanted to put an acknowledgement of the original reference into my translation. I didn't expect any difficulty, but I've been rather taken aback by the helpful responses: I seem to have stumbled on a real curiosity. TKR's very useful Language Hat thread link is enormously entertaining, but it's persuaded me to let sleeping dogs lie.

Answer (score 3):

This has given me a sharp admonition about the care needed in transforming idiom when translating. I'm always at pains to emphasise this when helping anyone with a rendition into Latin, and have many times discussed the degree of liberty that is allowable : for instance, is it legitimate to use *ad aram ducere* instead of the more authentic *in matrimonium*? (it is, according to an eminent English Latinist, but not everyone agrees).

I had almost forgotten that the same kind of problem awaits translators from other languages — and not only into English, but also into Latin from other languages, as the question and the subsequent comments well illustrates. This has been a useful reminder.